# TS React: Unexpected token

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript

I am using asp.net core and React.js for an application.Everything is happeing in visual studio. I am trying to create a schedule but I have an error when I use '`let ajax = new Ajax('Home/GetData', 'GET', false);` '. The error:

> Unexpected token. a constructor method accessor or property was
>   expected

Scheduler.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScheduleComponent, Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda, Inject } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Ajax } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { DataManager, ODataV4Adaptor, Query } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';

export default class Scheduler extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>  {

    private dataManager: object = []; 
    let ajax = new Ajax('Home/GetData', 'GET', false);  //here

    render() {

        <h1>nerge</h1>
        return <ScheduleComponent height='550px' selectedDate={new Date(2018, 1, 15)} eventSettings={{ dataSource: dataManager }}>
            <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month]} />

        </ScheduleComponent>;
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "WebApplication",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "4.4.45",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.3",
    "@types/webpack": "2.2.15",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "domain-task": "^3.0.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "history": "4.6.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "node-noop": "1.0.0",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "3.7.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule": "^18.1.44"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Get rid of the `let`. When defining a class property, you just use the property name itself, optionally with `public`/`private`/`protected`, but never with `let`.

Comment: Exactly, if you review https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html you can't define variables on a class, but you can define properties with [modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers)

Comment: Thank you for your respons. I tried that but after I have to use `ajax.onSuccess = function (value: any)` and I get the error:Subsequent property declarations must have the same type